# generate date range base on integers

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I have an array like this `[0,1,2,3 .. 23]` and they means hour in a day. How to use moment js to convert them to 12 hour then do date range?

my desire output is

```
['12am-1am','1am-2am','2am-3am' .. 11pm-12am]
```

my attempt failed coz I thought I don't need moment https://jsfiddle.net/s4L7hj1a

Comment: Please post code with your attempts

Comment: @MaximShoustin done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need moment.js

```js
var getFormattedHour = function(hour) {
  return (hour % 12 ? hour % 12 : 12) + ':00 ' + ((hour < 12) || (hour >= 24) ? 'AM' : 'PM');
}

var getHourRange = function(hour) {
    return getFormattedHour(hour) + ' - ' + getFormattedHour(hour + 1);
}

var hours = [];
for(var hour = 0; hour < 24; hour++) {
  hours.push(hour);
}

hours.map(function(hour) {
  console.log(getHourRange(hour));
});
```

Comment: I don't understand this line `hour % 12 ? hour % 12 : 12`,

Comment: @CeciliaChan It is used to convert 24h time to 12h.

Answer (score 1):

Using moment.js:

```
const moment = require('moment');

const start = moment().startOf('day');

const times = 24; // 24 hours   

for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    const toPrint = moment(start)
        .add(60 * i, 'minutes')
        .format('hh:mm A');

         console.log(toPrint);
}
```

This will give yo:

```
12:00 AM 
01:00 AM 
02:00 AM 
... 
...
10:00 PM 
11:00 PM
```

then you can add them in array as you like